# How do I get OpenMQ to redeliver messages?

Tags: spring, jms, openmq, openjms

I listened to an OpenMQ queue asynchronously. If I have an exception in the process of consuming a message, is there a way to get OpenMQ to push that message to me again?

```java
@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsQueueListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    jmsListenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    jmsListenerContainerFactory.setPubSubDomain(false);
    jmsListenerContainerFactory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    return jmsListenerContainerFactory;
}
```

```java
MessageConsumer receiver = session.createConsumer(destination);
receiver.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        TextMessage text = (TextMessage) message;
        System.out.println("Received message: " + message.getText());

        //The connection timed out when saving the message to the database
        repository.save(text);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the acknowledge mode of the session?

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I change the acknowledge to `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`. And invoke message.acknowledge() when process success, and  session.recover()
 when exception. This will fulfill my purpose. However, I encountered a new problem, I did not find how to set the maximum number of resends, and the interval time. @JoshMc

Comment: Hi Winston, if you would please edit your question to add the code showing the session setup with the original non-working acknowledge mode (I assume `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE`), then I think I can write a quick answer so you can give credit for the help I provided you in correcting the problem that your question was written about.

Comment: As for the question on how to set the maximum number of resends and interval time, this is a different question and this site is one question one answer per post, so it is better for you to add a new question on that subject.

Comment: @JoshMc  Ok, thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code showing the session setup with the original non-working acknowledge mode (I assume AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE).  That way my answer will make since.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is not backed out is that you have acknowledged mode set to `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE`.

```java
jmsListenerContainerFactory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

Change this to `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` like below:

```java
jmsListenerContainerFactory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

Use `message.acknowledge()` to commit the message.

Use `session.recover()` to back out the message.